# Automatic documentation tool for eclipse Java

Tags: java, documentation

is there an automatic documentation tool for eclipse? (Like the Ghost Doc Tool)
I'm working in Java and i want a reccomended tool.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a nice tool http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

It's built-in.

Just type `/**` [enter] above a method and it will autocomplete the javadoc.
Then just use the javadoc tool to generate the html documentation.

Obviously, all useful docs have to be written by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Another shortcut to generate Java document is (ALT+SHIFT+J) on selecting any  method or class or variable etc in your eclipse IDE.